# std::string::length vs strlen using Google Benchmark

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I wrote my first benchmark using Google Benchmark to check what is faster between the use of `std::string::length` and `strlen` to compute the length of a `std::string`.

I would like to know what I can improve in my code to use it as a base for future benchmarks. My main concerns are about:

- the creation of the `std::string` at the beginning of my functions: is it the right place to do it? Should I use fixtures? Or create a global `std::vector<std::string>` that contains every strings I'll use for my benchmark?
- the use of `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` and `benchmark::ClobberMemory`: I'm not sure I use these functions as I should. The idea is the following: I want to be sure the `std::string s` is created and stored into memory before entering in my loop and I want to be sure the functions `std::string::length` and `strlen` are really called and not optimized. Is it the good way to do it?
- the use of `DenseRange` to create a benchmark with multiple length of string. At first, I wanted to pass an `std::string` directly to my function but, apparently, only `int` can be returned by `state.range`. Is there another way to pass a string to my functions?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

#include <string>
#include <cstring>

static void BM_InneficientBasicStringLength(benchmark::State& state)
{
    std::string s;

    for (int i = 0; i < state.range(0); i++)
        s += 'a';

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(s.data());
    benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    size_t size;

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(size = strlen(s.c_str()));
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_InneficientBasicStringLength)->DenseRange(0, 100, 10);

static void BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix(benchmark::State& state)
{
    std::string s;

    for (int i = 0; i < state.range(0); i++)
        s += 'a';

    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(s.data());
    benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    size_t size;

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(size = s.length());
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix)->DenseRange(0, 100, 10);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

It compiles with: `g++ -o example example.cpp -lbenchmark -lpthread`.

---

**EDIT:** For your information, the results are better with `std::string::length` which have a constant complexity while `strlen` have
a linear complexity:

```
> ./example 
2020-08-14T14:48:17+02:00
Running ./example
Run on (12 X 3900 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x6)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x6)
  L2 Unified 1024 KiB (x6)
  L3 Unified 8448 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 5.18, 6.05, 6.32
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                        Time             CPU   Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/0             4.79 ns         4.79 ns    150060775
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/10            4.66 ns         4.66 ns    151148682
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/20            5.39 ns         5.39 ns    136288403
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/30            5.36 ns         5.35 ns    135353692
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/40            5.19 ns         5.18 ns    137059957
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/50            5.22 ns         5.22 ns    134737400
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/60            5.32 ns         5.32 ns    134098029
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/70            6.65 ns         6.65 ns    107061965
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/80            6.85 ns         6.85 ns    109856173
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/90            6.78 ns         6.78 ns    106762788
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength/100           6.66 ns         6.66 ns     98081332
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/0         3.01 ns         3.01 ns    231875548
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/10        3.06 ns         3.06 ns    221447369
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/20        2.96 ns         2.96 ns    237989703
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/30        2.98 ns         2.98 ns    234755616
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/40        2.99 ns         2.98 ns    231015140
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/50        2.94 ns         2.94 ns    223906062
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/60        3.04 ns         3.04 ns    225199556
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/70        3.07 ns         3.07 ns    230208201
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/80        3.02 ns         3.02 ns    219373040
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/90        3.10 ns         3.10 ns    219921248
BM_InneficientBasicStringLength_Fix/100       3.10 ns         3.10 ns    238076969
```

Comment: What did you find, could you post your results? I would expect string.length() to be much faster since it may only need to access an internal count that is made while the string is created.

Comment: Are you trying to imitate perl? `for (auto _ : state)`. Don't be obtuse in your code it is supposed to be human readable.

Comment: @MartinYork Almost all of the examples given on the GitHub of the project follow this pattern: https://github.com/google/benchmark#usage Whatever, what alternatives could I use?

Comment: Benchmarking calculating the string length is not representative of real world code. Compilers will be able to optimize this if they know anything about the string. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/6zd814). I also wouldn't trust any results that only take a few nanoseconds, it's likely that despite Google Benchmark's best efforts to avoid that, these low numbers will include overhead from benchmarking itself.

Comment: @G.Sliepen One of my concern is to avoid optimizations of the compiler. That's why I use `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` and `benchmark::ClobberMemory`. However, this is one of my questions: am I using this functions correctly in order to have a correct measure of `strlen` and `std::string::length`.
About the duration of my benchmark, that's all the problem with microbenchmarking. The idea is to take a very little piece of code outside of its context to measure its efficiency. To prevent any issue about the reproducibility, we can see each measures are performed at least 98081332 times.

Comment: @Pierre I don't think appealing to google is a good argument for doing it. Google in my experience has never been good at defining the best C++ practices (though they eventually catch up to the industry).  I would do something that expressed the intent of my actions. Every situation would be unique, but in this case maybe: `for (auto loopOver: state)` (expressing in english that we are looping over `state`. The point of code is to express your intent clearly to the next person that read the code.

Comment: This benchmark is meaningless because `string::length()` simply returns stored counter while `strlen` has to go through the whole string to determine its length.

Comment: @ALX23z I agree. My point was to write a first dummy benchmark to reuse the pattern for other and meaningful benchmarks.

Comment: Spelling: **Inefficient**.